# Query timeout all living people on WikiData

Tags: sql, sparql, wikidata

I have the following query to fetch all living people on wikidata but it's timing out. Any suggestions on how to optimize it or change it to make it run?

```
SELECT ?person ?personLabel WHERE {
  ?person wdt:P31 wd:Q5.
  OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P570 ?dateOfDeath }
  FILTER(!BOUND(?dateOfDeath))
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
```

Comment: that's the nature of public services, they have some limit set to avoid the service being stuck. Moreover, some queries might be harder for triple stores than others. There are two options, either you load Wikidata into your own triple store or you use the public Qlever service: https://qlever.cs.uni-freiburg.de/wikidata/WyTYvH - the later is most likely not in sync though

Comment: there is also no room for optimization here, the query is so simple, both using `filter not exist`, i.e. `SELECT ?person WHERE {
  ?person wdt:P31 wd:Q5.
  filter not exists { ?person wdt:P570 ?dateOfDeath }
}` and `minus` with `SELECT ?person WHERE {
  ?person wdt:P31 wd:Q5.
  MINUS {?person wdt:P570 ?dateOfDeath }
}` timeout.  there are `10 391 165` million persons, Blazegraph might have trouble with that kind of query or the query time limit is too low, Qlever works

Answer (score 0):

Extracting such a big dataset with a single SPARQL query is a bit unrealistic...

Probably it is more practical to parse a [Wikidata dump](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Database_download) to filter out what required: there are some libraries helping in this (here in [PHP](https://github.com/JeroenDeDauw/JsonDumpReader), [Go](https://gitlab.com/tozd/go/mediawiki) and [Scala](https://github.com/weso/wdsub)) and even online services providing Wikidata batch extraction (e.g. [Semantic Builders](https://semantic.builders/info/extract-large-wikidata-results)).